# Is there an efficient strategy for doing a fuzzy join on customer data to identify a single customer ID in R?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I wish to perform a "fuzzy-deduplication" on my customer data to derive a unique ID per customer where in the original data multiple IDs may have been entered for the same customer.

I have a data frame in R which contains a list of customers.  Each customer has an ID, First Name, Last Name, Email and Phone Number.

Many customers have been entered multiple times for different purchases.  Sometimes the old record (same ID) is reused, other times a new record and new ID are issued.

What is an appropriate strategy for deduplicating this data where I cannot rely on an exact match across all fields - e.g. misspelling of first name or only initial given, but other fields may match.

I currently do a dplyr left join on First name concatenated to Surname, then use Phone and Email as a validation check, but this may miss some records.  Loosening the match rules (all same Surname) results in too large a data frame.

(No code at the moment - this is more a request for general coding strategy and approach.

Are there any packages that handle these sorts of matches efficiently?)

Comment: Hava a look at packages `stringdist` and `fuzzyjoin`.

Comment: I've looked at fuzzyjoin and it struggles due to the volume of data being involved.  If I have 100,000 customer records (I have way more), to build a distance matrix of every record to every record becomes too big for the memory to cope.  What I am looking for is a strategy for making this join more efficient before calculating a distance measure.

Comment: Asking for libraries is off-site off-topic. What would satisfy you we cannot answer. "request for general coding strategy and approach" is too-broad off-topic. Fuzzy matching is a faq in R, SQL & other languages, so there is plenty of research you can do even in SO. Also research "data cleansing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before getting to the process of finding duplicates it is important to get/gather good data to begin with.

You have mentioned first name, last name, email and phone number. First names are good, since they usually don’t change unlike email addresses and phone numbers. Last names can change through marriage/divorce. Therefore, it is always good to have other time-invariant variables such as “date of birth” or “place of birth”.

Even with good data, there will always be a challenge matching first, last names and date of birth in a large customer database.

As you point out in your comments, a string distance matrix of 100,000 plus customers takes time and causes memory problems.

**One work around** here is to sort the data and break it into pieces. Create a string distance matrix on each small piece, get some likely matches and piece everything back together. There are different approaches on how to do that, and I will just show how it works in principle and maybe you can expand on this.

I downloaded some fake data of 1,000 records. Unfortunately, it does not contain duplicates, but for showing the Basic workflow it does not deed real duplicates.

The approach takes the following steps:

1. Create a name field based on last and first name.
2. Arrange it in ascending order (A-Z).
3. Break it down into groups of 50 customers (this is for my example data with 1,000 rows, actually running groups of 500 should be no problem in terms of speed and memory).
4. Create a nested tibble to work on with `purrr::map`.
5. Apply a customized `stringdistmatrix` function that works in the `dplyr` pipe and gives likely matches between names of customers as output.
6. Unnest the single results to get a complete list of potential
   matches.

The idea behind breaking down the data is that you do not need a string distance matrix of all 100,000 customers. Most of the names are so different that you do not even need to calculate a string distance. Sorting the names and working on small subsets is like narrowing down the search.

Of course this is just one way to break down the data. It is incomplete, since it misses, for example, all customers with a typo in the first letter of the last name. However, you can replicate this approach for other variables such as date of birth, number of characters in a name etc. Ideally you do different break downs and piece everything together in the end.

I downloaded some fake date via www.mockaroo.com. I tried to put it here with dput, but it was to long. So I just show you the head() of my data and you can create your own fake data or use real customer data.

One note regarding my customized version of `stringdistmatrix` which I named `str_dist_mtx`. When working with real data you should adjust the size of the group (in the example it is rather small n = 50). And you should adjust the string distance `string_dist` up until which you want to consider two differing names as potential matches. I took `6` to at least get some results, but I am not working with data which has real duplicates. So in a real application I would choose `1` or `2` to cover the most basic typos.

```
# the head() of my data
test_data <- structure(list(first_name = c("Gabriel", "Roscoe", "Will", "Francyne", 
"Giorgi", "Dulcinea"), last_name = c("Jeandeau", "Chmiel", "Tuckwell", 
"Vaggers", "Fairnie", "Tommis"), date_of_birth = structure(c(9161, 
4150, 2557, 9437, -884, -4489), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Below is the code I used.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(stringdist)

# customized stringdistmatrix function
str_dist_mtx <- function(df, x, string_dist, n) {

  temp_mtx = stringdistmatrix(df[[x]],df[[x]])

  temp_tbl = tibble(name1 = rep(df[[x]], each = n),
                    name2 = rep(df[[x]], times = n),
                    str_dist = as.vector(temp_mtx)) %>% 
             filter(str_dist > 0 & str_dist < string_dist) 

  temp_tbl[!duplicated(data.frame(t(apply(temp_tbl,1,sort)))),]

}

# dplyr pipe doing the job
test_data2 <- test_data %>%
                mutate(name = paste0(last_name, first_name)) %>% 
                arrange(name) %>%
                mutate(slice_id = row_number(),
                      slice_id = cut_width(slice_id, 50, center = 25)) %>% 
                nest(-slice_id) %>% 
                mutate(str_mtx = map(data,
                                     ~ str_dist_mtx(., "name", string_dist = 6, n = 50))) %>% 
                select(str_mtx) %>% 
                unnest()
```

Comment: Thanks for providing and sharing that TimTeaFan - I will endeavour to work through that example and test it / understand it before providing feedback / comments, but please be patient as I have a uni assignment to complete in the coming days so likely to be a bit preoccupied with that.

Comment: One interesting point I make in response to your comment that "first names don't often change" is that in the data set that I am building this for, first name variations are usually the biggest source of headaches.

This is due to data entry issues - e.g. a customer may be entered as Henrietta for one transactions, Hennie as the next, or customers who are married couples may be bundled together (John & Jane or John and Jane) or just listed separately (but with the same surname / email / phone number to verify).  The solution I am looking for thus has to be robust to this fuzziness.

Comment: Thanks for sharing mockaroo as well btw.  Looks like a useful resource for testing just this sort of thing.  Thanks for your assistance despite my request being apparently "off-site off-topic" :-)

Comment: Interesting, with our customer base (insurance) we usually get the first name right ;) Anyhow, I just showed one example of how one could break down a large database into bits that can be processed more easily. Ideally, you combine different ways to break the data down. Another example would be to group customers with the same date of birth. Here the underlying assumption is that there is no typo in date of birth, but that the data in other fields differs somehow.

Comment: Okay - making some progress on this and will post some sample code when it is complete.  Your approach of nesting and using a function to generate an internal tibble is exactly what I am after.  However, instead of splitting the data into 50 record slices, I am taking the approach of grouping the data on a common key before nesting - in my case Phone number and then email as I am looking for at least one form of ID beyond name to verify that it is likely to be the same person.  So far, it is looking promising.